# Glassmorphism background

Tags: css, react-native

I am trying to recreate the image below that gives the button a "opaque" or blurred transparency look. I have tried googling for an opaque background but did not find much. How can I recreate this look?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I have tried adding a blur with a reduced opacity but it did not give me the look I wanted

Answer (score 1):

The effect is called, I believe, glassmorphism.  It is generally achieved using [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter).  You can find a generator for this effect at https://css.glass/.  Here's some example CSS it kicked out that seems like it approaching the style in your image:

```css
.your-class-here {
  /* From https://css.glass */
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.19);
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(13px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(13px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

Obviously there's some extra properties in there you might not need, but you can strip out what you do.